# nuxtServerInit is being executed everytime navigation happens

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I assumed that nuxtServerInit gets called once at startup, when SSR happens.
However I realized that nuxtServerInit is executed everytime I navigate in the webapp.

Do I misunderstand the use of nuxtServerInit ?

[~/pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Queci.png)

console log, showing that nuxtServerInit is called every time I click around:

```
  nuxt:render Rendering url /view/list +21m
axios starting
axios done
  nuxt:render Data fetching /view/list: 444ms +0ms
  nuxt:render Rendering url /view/status +10s
axios starting
axios done
  nuxt:render Data fetching /view/status: 86ms +9s
  nuxt:render Rendering url /view/list +4s
axios starting
axios done
  nuxt:render Data fetching /view/list: 98ms +4s
  nuxt:render Rendering url / +3s
axios starting
axios done
  nuxt:render Data fetching /: 106ms +3s
  nuxt:render Rendering url /view/status +4s
axios starting
axios done
  nuxt:render Data fetching /view/status: 139ms +4s
```

~/store/index.js

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            myAvailableViews: [],
            isViewsInitiated: false
        },
        mutations: {
            setAvailableViews(state, views) {
                state.myAvailableViews = views;
            },
            setViewsInit(state, isInitialized) {
                state.isViewsInitiated = isInitialized;
            }
        },
        actions: {
            setAvailableViewsAction({ commit }) {
                commit('setAvailableViews', payload);
            },
            async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {

                console.log('axios starting');
                let list = await this.$axios.get('/my/rest/api/uri');
                console.log('axios done');

            }
        },
        getters: {
            getAvailableViews(state) {
                return state.myAvailableViews;
            },
            getViewsInitiated(state) {
                return state.isViewsInitiated;
            }
        }
    });
}

export default createStore;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually made a noob error, using normal html `<a>` anchor tags instead of `<nuxt-link>` and this way the pages always fully got server side rendered
Once I performed the replacements, all works correctly.